# Image tag of react-native-image-progress

Tags: reactjs, react-native

in Image tag of react-native-image-progress the style property does not support borderRadius .Is there any alternative for that?
I want circle Image.

I already tried by using borderRadius property but image only shows width and height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write borderRadius={5} outside the style and parallel to the style and other props of your component rather than writing it inside the style.